# Drag and Drop from Silverlight to WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, drag-and-drop, silverlight-4.0

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to Drag some item (let's say an image with an id) in silverlight and drop it in a listbox in WPF.

If you have please help ;)

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1):

Drag drop to a Silverlight application from other surfaces outside of the Silverlight application is available only in Silverlight 4 and is limited to a file list payload.

Hence the only drag drop function you may be able to achieve between a WPF app and Silverlight is if you initiate the drag operation in the WPF app and include a standard file list as part of the Data attached to the drag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AnthonyWJones. Silverlight does not have the System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop method that WPF has, so you cannot initiate a "real" drag&drop. You can drag & drop controls within your app, but it is not possible to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony and Timores are correct in their responses, but I'll try to get creative with some ideas here:

- If you can leverage the same backend services, perhaps when a drag begins (MouseDown + MouseMove) you could send a chunk of XAML up to a service to store/cache the content, and when a drag ends on the other application (MouseEnter + MouseUp over the drop target), you could call that service to pull down the cached content
- In Silverlight 4, you have access in the local file system to the users "My" folders.  You may be able to use a temporary file and the drag begin/drag end events described above to transfer you XAML chunk from one app to another.  Refer to http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#localfiles
- If you are wanting to drag and drop text, you might be able to utilize the clipboard.  So when a drag begins, copy text into the clipboard.  When you end your drag in the other app, read from the clipboard and add the contents to the drop target